# Tkinter creating two windows instead of one

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I have created this tkinter widget, but when I run the code I get a MainWindow and a window that is labeled tk when I only want the one (MainWindow).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import backend


def Sll_command():
    row = backend.straightLineLink()
    print(row)



style = Style()
style.configure('W.TButton', front =('calibri', 10, 
'bold', 'underline'), foreground = 'red')

window = Tk()

window.wm_title("MainWindow")
window.resizable(width=True , height=True)

Grid.rowconfigure(window,0,weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(window, 0, weight=1)

b1 = Button(window, text = "SLL",
        style = 'W.TButton',
        command=Sll_command,)
b1.grid(row=2,column=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Move `window = Tk()` at top, should be the **first** statement.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. Thank you so much